# Ionic pass *ng-for information into query params

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an *ng-for loop, churning out ion-items, but I want those items to route to another page, but pass the index of that item, as a query parameter.

Here is my code:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; index as i;" 
    [routerLink]="['/itempage']" [queryParams]="{id: 'i'}" 
    routerDirection="forward">
    <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

I have no idea how to get the { q: 'i' } part to actually make i equal to the index, I keep getting errors and such.

Comment: can you post the errors?

Comment: I think this `[queryParams]="{id: 'i'}"` should look like this `[queryParams]="{id: i}"` because you are setting the id to 'i' (string)

Comment: @JosefKatič That worked! How silly of me.

Comment: I will post it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting an index there but you are setting `id` to `'i'` which is string.

Change it to this `[queryParams]="{id: i}"`